# Setting vm.dirty_ratio per cgroup

Tags: linux, kernel, cgroups

I was wondering if there is a way to set `vm.dirty_ratio` per cgroup? I see that the cgroup2 [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html#writeback#) mentions writeback but it seems that it will only use limits imposed by the memory controller to calculate the ratio and doesn't actually provide a way to override it. Or am I wrong?

I would like to create two cgroups, without memory limits imposed, but with different values for `vm.dirty_ratio`.